# org.hibernate.TransientObjectException when all @OneToMany are cascade=ALL

Tags: java, hibernate, guava

I have a small data structure data structure that I serialize in Hibernate using JPA annotations:

(below is very much simplified)

```
public class Result {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   public int id;


   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   @OrderColumn("row")
   @JoinColumn("ResultId)
   public List<Row> rows
}

public class Row {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   public int id;

   @ElementCollection
   @OrderColumn("col")
   public List<Double> value;
}
```

When I try to `persist()` a Result, I get TransientObjectException. How can that be? Shouldn't cascade=ALL take care of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, I've run into quite an interaction between Hibernate and Guava (Google Collections). In fact, this one feature of Guava that really needs to be more explicitly announced.

The code sample in my question was incomplete. The relevant (and missing) detail was the fact that I had a constructor of `Result` that took `List<List<Double>>` as parameter - that being more natural for the rest of the app.

Unfortunately, Hibernate is not good at storing two-dimensional arrays, so the `Row` class was a quick workaround.

To maintain the interface with the rest of the code,  I convert the `List<List<>>` to `List<Row>` in the constructor using - what else - `Lists.transform` from Guava.

When I tried to save the resulting objects to DB, I got the exception from Hibernate:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: <my class here>
```

I debugged a bit deeper, and I realized that the `Row` object had `setId` called on it was not the row object that was getting `getId` called (I had getters and setters - another simplification in my code sample).

Then it dawned on me. `transform()` produces a *view* of the underlying list, not a copy. Every time I ask for a transformed object, it's created from scratch, with brand new "id" field initialized to 0.

Let this be a lesson: if your transform adds a possibility  of extra state, follow the suggestion in Guava's `Lists.transform` docs:

> To avoid lazy evaluation when the returned list doesn't need to be a
>   view, copy the returned list into a new list of your choosing.